# jPOS Gradle build file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, jpos

By default if i run the gradle installApp command in windows cmd it generates a jar file with name jpos-1.9.8.jar. But my project requires me to generate the jar with projectName.jar for example myproject.jar and not jpos-1.9.8.jar.

I tried understanding the build.gradle file but i am not able to figure out from where project.name and project.version properties are being read. I tried changing the rootProject.name property in settings.gradle file to myproject name but that also didn't work.

How can i customize the jar name for this jPOS project?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet into your build.gradle:

```
archivesBaseName = 'myproject'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I knew of this workaround but wanted that my project.name and project.version should be picked dynamically. I have found the solution. I need to set the version inside project level build.gradle and in settings.gradle i need to change the rootProject.name to my project name. Plus my project subfolder name should be same as rootProject.name.